# Is every vector space isomorphic to a direct product of one-dimensional vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-product

**Question:** Is every vector space isomorphic to a direct product of one-dimensional vector spaces?

I know every vector space is a direct sum of one-dimensional vector spaces, since every vector space has a basis. Is there any similar theorem for direct product?

Comment: Every vector space is isomorphic to $ \mathbb{F}^u $ for some (possibly infinite / transfinite) $ u $ so ...

Comment: Every product of one-dimensional vector spaces has finite or uncountable dimension.

Comment: @DanielFischer Maybe edit a "of one-dimensional vector spaces" into that comment.

Comment: @Christoph Good point. Thanks.